# Traslation of Marriage Certificate in Italy

Tags: marriage, translations

I have just received my apostilled marriage certificate from South Africa and here in Italy the local authorities (Comune) says it needs to be translated as well.
The marriage Certificate is required to apply for my husband's Permesso di Soggiorno from the Questura.
My question is: where can I trace a recognized translator?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you could ask the *Comune*, they may know someone or even have list.

If that does not work, a simple google search for either of

- traduttore certificato + [name of your city / next major city / region]
- traduttore giurato + [name of your city / next major city / region]

will probably give you a few leads. If you don't specify a location, I also found websites that seem to offer such services (though likely only passing on to someone else in the end).

I assume you need a certified translation. When you ask for a *preventivo* (cost estimate), make sure to specify exactly what you need the translation for and convince yourself that they are able to deliver that.

Comment: I found an accredited translator through a non profit organization here in Caserta. Cost will be 60 Euros for both documents including all stamps etc